# Not Seeing <prijectname>csproj file in .net core project directory

Tags: file, asp.net-core, project, missing-data, csproj

[image]

csproj file is missing in solution file .
FYI : I am using VS 2019

Comment: I can see there is file named `WebApplication9` in your screenshot and it looks like the project (.csproj) file. I believe you need to rename the file and manually add the .csproj extension

Comment: As Mohsin pointed out, `WebApplication9` _is_ your project file. It says so in the type column. You might want to enable _Show file extensions_ option to actually see it https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebApplication9 is a csproj file, Check it out from View ->and tik mark Filename extensions ,So that you will be able to see the extension